# Convert signed to unsigned int column

Tags: mysql

How can I convert a signed int column to unsigned in MySQL?

I set a column to signed in `CREATE TABLE` and need to set it to `UNSIGNED` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
```

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY col_name bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0';
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALTER TABLE` to change the datatype of your table column. It can be done as follows -

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name UNSIGNED INT;
```

Read more about [ALTER TABLE here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)